# RecyclerView CardView onItemClick

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Got stuck on this problem for few days hope to find the solution.

I am unable to pass the data written on the card (Card View) to the next activity.

For clicking card, I am implementing its onClickListner in its recyclerView Adapter.

I want to pass the position of the card clicked but since card View does not support onItemClickListner I am facing the problem.

RecyclerViewAdapter class

```
public class RVAdapter extends recyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

 int position;
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder holder, int i) {
    setEventsForViews(holder, i);
}

private void setEventsForViews(PersonViewHolder holder, int i) {
    position = i;
    holder.cv.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Navigator.toAddFriends(context, placeList.get(getPosition()).getPlaceId());
}

public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cv;

    PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
    }

}
```

I tried to set up a variable position and tried to pass its value but since onBindViewHolder is called intially for all items in the view and I end up in setting the value of position as last one. I know this is the wrong approach but as I am new to this card View thing please suggest me any good and clean way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Vikas. Did you check my answer? Let me know if I can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new interface, like:

```
public interface RecyclerViewClickListener {
public void recyclerViewListClicked(View v, int position);
}
```

On your Fragment/Activity, implement the new interface:

```
public class MyFragment extends BaseFragment implements RecyclerViewClickListener { }
```

Now, you will be forced to implement the interface method `recyclerViewListClicked(View v, int position)` on your Fragment/Activity.
Do that so you can do whatever you want when one item is clicked. Do it like so:

```
 @Override
public void recyclerViewListClicked(View v, int position) {
    myList.get(position);
}
```

Now lets go to your Adapter.
On your adapter constructor, add a new listener parameter. It's **type** is the **interface** we have just created (don't forget to create a private static listener and set it on your constructor):

```
private static RecyclerViewClickListener mListener;

public myListAdapter(List<Thing> things, final Context context, RecyclerViewClickListener itemClickListener) {
    mThings = things;
    mContext = context;

    mListener = itemClickListener;
}
```

Inside your adapter, on your ViewHolder, implement `View.OnClickListener` like:

```
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
```

You will now be forced do @Override the onClickMethod inside your ViewHolder. Do it:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { }
```

On your ViewHolder constructor, set the onClickListener of your view. Like:

```
public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        myCardViewLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

Now implement the behaviour to your ViewHolder `onClickMethod`. In this case, I call the `recyclerViewListClicked` method of the static listener we declared in our adapter. This method is the one we have @Overriden in our fragment/activity, so it requires the `position` parameter.

Get the position by calling `getLayoutPosition()` inside your view holder. It will look like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mListener.recyclerViewListClicked(v, getLayoutPosition());
    }
```

Finally, get back to your fragment/activity, and pass the listener to the adapter constructor with `this` (since now we implement the interface `RecyclerViewClickListener` it can just pass itself as a listener to the adapter):

```
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this.mList, this.getActivity(), this))
```

Now, when you click on a `myCardViewLayout` on your list items it's going to call the `recyclerViewListClicked(View v, int position)` of your Fragment/Activity and you will be able to work with the position parameter as you'd like.
You can do this to any layout you want to get a click event from inside your list. Just replace `myCardViewLayout.setOnClickListener(this)` inside your ViewHolder constructor with `myDesiredToHaveOnClickListenerLayout.setOnClickListener(this)`.

Hope this helps.

@EDIT:

Some tips:

- Remove `implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener` from your adapter.
- And looks like you don't need to call `setEventsForViews(holder, i)` on your `onBindViewHolder` anymore. Confirm?

@UPDATE
This is how your ViewHolder will look like:

```
public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    CardView cv;

    PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);

        cv.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mListener.recyclerViewListClicked(v, getLayoutPosition());
    }

}
```

Comment: sorry for delay Dan and thank you for your help. I tried your solution everything was fine but I was stuck in getLayoutPosition() I don't get where to define its definition.

Comment: @VikasChandra `getLayoutPosition()` is a method of your ViewHolder, so you can call it anywhere inside your ViewHolder. In your case, you will call it inside the `onClick()` method we've just @Overriden. I have updated my answer to show you how it will look like.

Comment: @VikasChandra any progress?

Comment: Thanks @Dan for your answer I finally able to do it... Thank you very much.. :)

Comment: @VikasChandra could you please accept the answer, then? Thanks.

Comment: @DanXPrado Thanks for your solution, Now I have implemented the same solution to my adapter.If I debug ,Bkpoint reaches onClick() in the adapter.Now how to start a fragment from the onClick() , I dont get the getFragmentManager() in the Adapter since its not a fragment.

In other words how to use the getLayoutPosition in the calling fragment

Comment: @Raghu your `onClick` method inside the adapter will trigger the `recyclerViewListClicked()` method of your listener. Since you have implemented this listener in your activity/fragment and passed itself to the adapter, the `recyclerViewListClicked()` of your activity/fragment will be called and you can do whatever you need in your fragment activity. You won't be doing any logic inside the `onClick()` method of your adapter. You call the listener method and it will call the activity/fragment that implements that listener. Try following my answer and let me know if you have any questions.